Is it possible to deploy using Terraform and Azure DevOps Pipelines to a non-cloud cluster?
Context:
I have a service connection / environment in Azure DevOps for my local cluster which is inside of a virtual machine and I'm able to deploy resources through helm charts.
I want to create a pipeline for infrastructure deployment with terraform but I don't know if I'm able to get kubeconfig path o kubeconfig content to set the terraform "kubernetes" provider through variables.
I have done a helm chart for infra deployments but I don't believe it's a good idea and should migrate to terraform.
Has anyone done that anytime? Is it possible?
PD: here's a piece of my deployment .yaml for more context of how I'm doing it right now
stages:
  - stage: DEV
    condition: eq(variables.environment, 'DEV')
    jobs:
      - deployment:
        displayName: "Deploy ${{parameters.environment}} infrastructure"
        environment:
          name: 01-DEV
          resourceType: Kubernetes
        variables:
          - group: "dev"
        workspace:
          clean: all
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - checkout: self

                - task: gitversion/setup@0
                  displayName: Setup GitVersion
                  inputs:
                    versionSpec: '5.x'

                - task: gitversion/execute@0
                  displayName: Execute GitVersion
                  inputs:
                    useConfigFile: true
                    configFilePath: $(gitVersionFile)

                - task: KubectlInstaller@0
                  displayName: Install Kubectl

                - task: HelmInstaller@1
                  displayName: Instal Helm

                - task: ReplaceTokens@1
                  displayName: Variable substitutions in values.yaml
                  inputs:
                    sourcePath: charts/Infra
                    filePattern: "values.yaml"
                    tokenRegex: __(\w+[\.\w+]*)__

                - task: HelmDeploy@0
                  displayName: Package Helm Chart
                  inputs:
                    command: "package"
                    chartPath: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/charts/Infra"
                    chartVersion: "$(GitVersion.SemVer)"
                    save: false
                    arguments: --app-version $(Build.BuildNumber)
                    destination: $(Agent.TempDirectory)

                - task: HelmDeploy@0
                  displayName: Deploy chart
                  inputs:
                    namespace: $(Environment.ResourceName)
                    command: upgrade
                    chartType: FilePath
                    chartPath: "$(Agent.TempDirectory)/Infra-$(Build.BuildNumber).tgz"
                    arguments: "--create-namespace"


In Azure Pipelines, to use the kubeconfig file as the authentication for Terraform kubernetes provider, you can do like as below:

Get the kubeconfig file. By default, path of this file is "~/.kube/config" on the server machine that your on-premises Kubernetes is hosted.

In the Azure DevOps project where you want to run the pipeline, upload the config file as a secure file from your local path.


In the pipeline, you can use the DownloadSecureFile@1 task to download the secure file to the agent machine. This task will automatically generate an output variable to store the local path of the downloaded secure file.

Then on the subsequent tasks, you can use this output variable (ReferenceName.secureFilePath) or its corresponding environment variable to pass the local path. In your Terraform files, you can pass the file path using the environment variable.


See Below example as reference:
# azure-pipelines.yml

steps:
# The set the custom ReferenceName as 'myKubeconfig' on this task.
# The variable name is 'secureFilePath' by default.
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  displayName: 'Download kubeconfig file'
  name: myKubeconfig
  inputs:
    secureFile: config

# On the subsequent tasks, can access the file path via the output variable or its corresponding environment variable.
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Print file path'
  inputs:
    pwsh: true
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host $(myKubeconfig.secureFilePath)
      Write-Host $env:MYKUBECONFIG_SECUREFILEPATH



